# How to take a value from readonly object with formatted string as a key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have code similar to the below, there are an object `errorMessages` and some fields. For each field I have several error messages in `errorMessages`, but I cannot use a formatted string to get a value from the readonly object:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const errorMessages = {
  emailInvalid: "Invalid email address",
  emailAlreadyExists: "This email is already exists",
  phoneInvalid: "Invalid phone number",
  phoneNotAllowed: "Phone region is not allowed"
} as const;

const fields = ["email", "phone"];

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (field: string) => {
    const error = `${field}Invalid`;
    setError(errorMessages[error]); // Here I got an error
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{error}</h1>
      {fields.map((field) => (
        <button key={field} onClick={() => handleClick(field)}>
          {field} error
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error says:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ readonly required: "This field
> is required"; readonly emailInvalid: "Invalid email address"; readonly
> phoneInvalid: "Invalid phone number"; }'.   No index signature with a
> parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ readonly required:
> "This field is required"; readonly emailInvalid: "Invalid email
> address"; readonly phoneInvalid: "Invalid phone number"; }'.ts(7053)

Is it possible to solve this without changing `errorMessages`? Please give me some advice.

I don't know why, but on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tristan-i090q0?file=/src/App.tsx:0-736) it works even with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the above

```
interface PropsErrorMessages {
  [key: string]: string;
}
const errorMessages: PropsErrorMessages = {
  emailInvalid: "Invalid email address",
  emailAlreadyExists: "This email is already exists",
  phoneInvalid: "Invalid phone number",
  phoneNotAllowed: "Phone region is not allowed"
}
```

UPDATED:

OR

```
setError(errorMessages[error as keyof errorMessages]);
```

Comment: It is not readonly now, I can change error messages

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The error is happening because errorMessage has no declared type so becomes the interface itself. The above example I have provided ensures that errorMessages can have any string value as a key - not just emailInvalid, emailAlreadyExists, phoneInvalid, phoneNotAllowed etc.

Comment: If you do : errorMessages[ `${field}Invalid`] it will result in an error because it is dynamically created. Allowing the key of errorMessages to be a string as I have specified above is a better solution. An alternative is to do:  errorMessages[ `${field}Invalid` as keyof errorMessages]

Comment: The alternative with `errorMessages[${field}Invalid as keyof typeof errorMessages]` is exactly what I wanted.  Can you add it to the answer please, I'm gonna accept it